# Gridview problem only when a minSdkVersion is specified

Tags: android

I am displaying some thumbnails with Gridview. The strange problem I am having is that if android:minSdkVersion is not specified in the manifest the thumbnails are properly spaced but if I specify the minSdkVersion (needs to be 4 or more) the thumbnails merge together horizontally.

This problem is only on my test phone, a T Mobile pulse mini, I get no such problem on the emulator.

Grateful for any bright ideas on this one.

The XML is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <!--thumbnails-->
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="none" 
        android:gravity="center"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Property "auto_fit" is available after API version 4.
So in the line

```
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
```

You will have to specify the number of columns.
For more information refer

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#AUTO_FIT